# How to read PDF files using tabula in google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, tabula

Hi Im currently trying to do some automation that will convert PDF files to CSV then load it into big query. the only issue that im having is reading and converting the PDF file from a **Google Drive Folder**.

I'm currently using tabula via colab.

```
--------------------
My code: (Note that i've already installed everything...)
import tabula

# Read pdf into list of DataFrame
df = tabula.read_pdf('/content/drive/My\ Drive/GDriveToGCS-Folder/TestPDFFileConversion.pdf', pages=2)
--------------------
Error Message: 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My\\ Drive/GDriveToGCS-Folder/TestPDFFileConversion.pdf'
--------------------
```

Has any one tried this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this backslash

```
My\ Drive
```

Replace it with just

```
My Drive
```

It's already inside python string quote: '/content/drive/My Drive/...'